# JavaScript post request error 422 with FastApi python server

Tags: javascript, python, html

I just want to make a simple login page with javascript and python. Website should send a post request to my python api. But I am getting error 422 which means Unprocessable entity and javascript doesnt print the json response so I cant understand why I am getting 422 error.

My JavaScript code:

```
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

function submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const nameInput = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  const passwdInput = document.getElementById("passwd").value;

  console.log({"first_name": nameInput, "password": passwdInput})
  const url = "http://192.168.1.5:800/login";

  fetch('http://192.168.1.5:800/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({first_name:nameInput, password: passwdInput}),
    mode: 'no-cors',
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const json = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitForm);
```

And my python server code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI , Response, status, HTTPException
import uvicorn
import socket
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.params import Body
import sqlite3
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import json

class login(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    password: str

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.post("/login")
def login(data: login):
    print(data.first_name, data.password)
    return {"message": "Got It!"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host=IPAddr, port=800)
```

Any help is accepted.

Comment: What does the error message say? You should be getting both a traceback in the python terminal, as well as an error description in the HTTP response (look in the browser network tab).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set up routes like that without importing flask. I think the invalid data may be from that. Here are some packages to help:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from os import path
```

os.path allows you to use files if you need it

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was just because the "mode: 'no-cors'" parameter. When I remove this parameter I worked succesfully. So final code is something like this:

```
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

function submitForm(event) {
event.preventDefault();

const nameInput = document.getElementById("fname").value;
const passwdInput = document.getElementById("passwd").value;

console.log({"first_name": nameInput, "password": passwdInput})
const url = "http://192.168.1.5:800/login";

fetch('http://192.168.1.5:800/login', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({first_name:nameInput, password: passwdInput}),

})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following article

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

> Note that mode: "no-cors" only allows a limited set of headers in the
> request:
>
> Accept
>
> Accept-Language
>
> Content-Language
>
> Content-Type with a value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multip
> art/form-data, or text/plain

Due to this, the request header "Content-Type" remains text/plain causing the 422 error.

One solution would be to remove the "mode" attribute from the fetch request. You could run the server on localhost to prevent CORS issues.